# Convert time from UTC to Local timezone

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm sending an email and I want to get the time when a file is uploaded, but the default time is in UTC.

I tried several things to convert from UTC to Central Time for example. Is there any expression to convert from UTC in Azure Logic Apps?

I tried the following expression:

```
convertTimeZone('HH:mm:ss', 'UTC', 'Pacific Standard Time')
```

Comment: what error do you get when you run the above?

Comment: @TimothyRadier InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' inputs at line '1' and column '3277': 'In the template language function 'convertFromUtc', the value provided for the time zone id 'Pacific Standard Time ' was not valid. '.

Comment: which format are you passing as 'HH:mm:ss', is it just the time component?

Comment: Yes, just the time component.

Comment: Since you are not using a full timestamp try the below:
convertTimeZone('12:22:33', 'UTC', 'Pacific Standard Time','HH:mm:ss')
where 12:22:33 is the time

Comment: That worked, but if there any way to convert to Central time or get the local time instead of Pacific?

Comment: for central time, use Central Standard Time, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones for all supported timezones

Comment: Perfect, last question, is there a way to replace the 12:22:33 with current time instead of passing 12:22:33?

Comment: for that try formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'),'HH:mm:ss')

Comment: It worked, Thank you for all your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Timothy Radier , you can use combination of both formatDateTime ,convertTimeZone expression to covert the UTC time zone to Central standard  time zone.

```
formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(), 'UTC', 'Central Standard Time'),'HH:mm:ss')
```

Alternatively , By default central time zone is 5 hours behind the utc time you can also use 'subtractFromTime' expression to convert utc time to central time.

```
formatDateTime(subtractFromTime(utcNow(),5,'Hour'),'HH:mm:ss')
```

Here is the reference output :

[image]