# Logic Apps: How to set local date/time with UTC hour offset

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, datetime-format

In Azure Logic Apps I want to convert the UTC time.

If the UTC date/time is: 2023-10-30T18:31:05.123

I want to convert the UTC date/time to EST and format the date/time as: 2023-10-30T14:31:05.123-04:00

I've tried this: convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz')

But the result is this: 2023-10-30T14:31:05.123+00:00

i.e. I'm not getting the correct UTC hour offset, it should be -04:00.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert time from UTC to Local timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69271470/convert-time-from-utc-to-local-timezone)

Comment: No it did not. The issue is with hour offset (-04:00).

Comment: The only solution I've found thus far is to find the hours difference and store into variable (TZDiff):

`split(dateDifference(convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time'),utcNow()),':')[0]`

`concat(convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','Eastern Standard Time','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff'),'-',variables('TZDiff'),':00')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

In Logic apps the connector gives us +00:00 even i have tried:

[image]

You are going in right direction, getting the difference and then concatenating it and AFAIK, there is no other way to do so other than that(or by manually concatenating -4:00 at end):

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I had originally just concatenated -04:00, but this fails when DST ends and the time zone offset becomes -05:00.